# Why does DestroyFVKeyOnStandby no longer work to secure Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I noticed that using the DestroyFVKeyOnStandby option for FileVault 2 in terminal no longer works since upgrading to Mavericks. Usually you type the following in terminal:

```
sudo pmset -a DestroyFVKeyOnStandby 1 | sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
```

The first command is suppose to cause the FileVault key to be destroyed when you put your Mac to sleep. The second one causes the system to store a copy of memory to the disk, and will remove power to memory. After you close your MacBook or put your desktop Mac (10.8.5) to sleep after a few seconds then tried to open the lid / turn it on you would have 2 separate login screens.

One is the FileVault login window, the second is the standard OSX login prompt.

Since upgrading to Mavericks however this does not work. The Mac wakes up almost instantly and doesn't prompt for the FileVault password. Other settings I've played such as changing the timeout for sleep doesn't seem to affect it. My current `"pmset -g live"` stats are:

> ```
> DestroyFVKeyOnStandby     1
> Active Profiles:
> AC Power      -1*
> Currently in use:
> hibernatemode        25
> halfdim              1
> womp                 1
> networkoversleep     0
> sleep                15 
> Sleep On Power Button 1
> ttyskeepawake        1
> hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
> autorestart          1
> disksleep            10
> displaysleep         10
> ```

Was this purposely removed from Mavericks? Is it a bug? Can't seem to find the answer anywhere else.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic - will try to migrate to Apple.SE

Comment: Security people really really care about this. It's essential cyber hygiene for protecting sensitive data.